# Separate Thread won't run, blocking main UI

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program which executes a set of PowerShell commands. Now the thing is that i need to update the status of a label and show an icon at the time when the user clicks a certain option and the process of executing commands starts. If i just type the commands before the try-catch statement they are executed at the end after the whole try-catch statement end. So i tried running them on a separate Thread in the code provided bellow, but in this case they are not even executed, just the try-catch block is. The method NORMAL_MODE() is triggered by mouse click.

```
@FXML
    private void NORMAL_MODE(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LABEL.setText("123");
                ICON.setVisible(true);
            }
        }).start();
        try (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.openSession()) {
            PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Windows\\Temp”");
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
            System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Windows\\Prefetch”");
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
            System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Documents and Settings”");
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
            System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location $env:TEMP");
            System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
            response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item -whatif -Recurse -Force");
            System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
        } catch(PowerShellNotAvailableException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap which part is executed in a separate thread. GUI updates should always be made on the JavaFX thread. Conversely, blocking calls and other significant work should *not* be done on the JavaFX thread.

Answer (score 1):

All JavaFX event handlers run on the JavaFX application thread and those handler need to return quickly, which is not what happens with `PowerShell`. Any modification to the GUI needs to happen on the JavaFX application thread.

It seems like you just moved the wrong code to the background thread.

The [`Task` class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) can help with handling completion/exception of code executed on a background thread.

```
@FXML
private void NORMAL_MODE(){
    LABEL.setText("123");
    ICON.setVisible(true);

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
             try (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.openSession()) {
                PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Windows\\Temp”");
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
                System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Windows\\Prefetch”");
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
                System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location “C:\\Documents and Settings”");
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item * -whatif -recurse -force");
                System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-Location $env:TEMP");
                System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
                response = powerShell.executeCommand("Remove-Item -whatif -Recurse -Force");
                System.out.println(response.getCommandOutput());
            }
            return null;
        }

    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        // todo: update gui to indicate success
    });
    task.setOnFailed(event -> {
        // todo: update gui to indicate an exception happened
    });

    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

The `onSucceeded` and `onFailed` event handlers are executed on the JavaFX application thread, so you don't need to use `Platform.runLater` for modifications to the GUI done in those handlers.